# Transpositioning and matching values

Tags: excel

Is there any formula or built in tool in Excel to make such a thing?

I have table:

```
   |   A    |   B   |   C   |
1  | nam1   | val1  | val2  |
2  | nam2   | val3  | val4  |
3  | nam3   | val5  | val6  |
```

I want this to look like that:

```
1 |  val1 | nam1
2 |  val2 | nam1
3 |  val3 | nam2
4 |  val4 | nam2
```

I want to assign names to values with should be in rows.

Comment: Why not just copy columns B and C into a new single column, sort it and then use the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)?

Comment: There is more columns = 5 , I know about VLOOKUP function, but i was thinking if I Can make it easier way

Comment: Then look at the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592). Provide some maths on the row and column as you fill down and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess getting someone to write formulae for you counts as easier! Assuming a layout as shown I suggest two formulae because one column repeats a column and another column lists a matrix (which I have extended with two further columns in view of your Comment). Applying [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) as suggested by @Jeeped:

In Row 1 (in the example ColumnG) and copied down to suit:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,INT((ROW()-1)/4),MOD(ROW()-1,4))
```

In H1 and copied down to suit:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW()-1)/4),0)
```

The row numbers of the formulae are used to calculate the appropriate offsets for rows and columns relative to the reference cells.

[image: SO33733003 example]